# Cakephp - check if owner of item on website is currently logged in User

Tags: php, function, cakephp

I have a couple of different 'items' on my website that I am building with cakePHP, for instance a Recipe and a ShoppingList.

I want certain items in my view (e.g. update and delete functionality links) to only be visible to the person who uploaded that item.

I want to add a function that would compare any given id to the currently logged in user's id. It would look something like this:

```
public function compareUser($id){
    if(!empty($this->userInfo) && $this->userInfo['User']['id'] == $id){
        return true;
    }
}
```

$this->userInfo is set in beforeFilter:

```
$this->userInfo = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))));
```

I have tried putting it in my appController, but that doesn't seem to work.

How can I implement this properly? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, this is a really nice first post, I would consider editing it to add the PHP tag to get additional visibility. :)

Comment: Also see [this post](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/10/05/common-cakephp-problems-and-solutions/) on some ideas on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best done using the isAuthorized($user) method.

All the information about your current user is stored in $this->Session->read('Auth.User') (this retrieves the full array, if you just wanted to get their 'id' you use $this->Auth->user('id') as you already did).
From the above it should hopefully be clear that normally you don't need to retrieve the user's details through an extra query as they are already stored in the Auth component of the session :)

Make sure in the setup for your Auth component you have 'authorize' => 'controller' and add the following to your AppController:

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
    //I want the default to be allow the user access so I will return true
    return TRUE;
}
```

Then add the following to your RecipesController (and ShoppingListsController if you want the same thing there):

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
    if ($this->action === 'update' || $this->action === 'delete') {
        $recipe = $this->Recipe->find(
            'first',
            'conditions' => array(
                'id' => $this->params['pass'][0]
            )
            'fields' => array(
                'user_id'
            )
        );
        if ($this->Auth->user('id') == $recipe['Recipe']['user_id']) {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return parent::isAuthorized($user);
}
```

Now if someone tries to access www.yourDomain.com/recipes/update/2 or www.yourDomain.com/recipes/delete/2 it will check if the current user's id is 2, if it is you're good to go, if not then it blocks them from that page.

Edit:

Easiest way to have a method accessible from all places I would suggest putting it in the AppModel that way all your models will inherit it:

```
//inside AppModel
public function isOwnedBy($id) {
    if (AuthComponent::user('id) == $id) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not sure if this was the answer I needed.

Currently in the view I have the following code:

    if(!empty($userInfo) && $recipe['Recipe']['user_id'] == $userInfo['User']['id']){
a block of code that only the owner of the item can see
}

I want to replace the if statement with a function I could use anywhere on the site, because I need it quite a lot. Is there a way to do this?

I'm sorry if I have misunderstood your answer, I am still quite a newbie ;)

Comment: @MarjoleinVerbeek In the end you'll need proper checks at controller or model level thogh, as everything in the view is just cosmetics and doesn't provide any kind of security. However there is a flaw in this answers code, comparing the row ID to the user ID doesn't add up, instead you'd want to test against the user ID that is stored in the row (see for example http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authorization-who-s-allowed-to-access-what), or use ACL in case you're having self-destructive tendencies.

Comment: Thank you! I was just having dinner and then I realised that I was being an idiot for trying to call functions in my view. ;) I'm now going to put it in my model, call it in my controller and set the boolean in a variable for my view so I can make the check there :) The authorize function is, now that I think of it, what I needed, because hiding a link won't stop users from accessing a page. Thanks a bunch! I wish I could upvote your answer, but I don't have enough rep :(

Comment: I've added a function which you can just stick in the AppModel and call from somewhere else as $this->anyModel->isOwnedBy($id).  As ndm said though, it is best to have proper checks in the controller or model and use different views for different privelleges :)

@ndm You're absolutely right, I was thinking about my own project where the users need access to only their own profiles.  I've changed the code to get the user id in the recipe first, I believe that is correct now? Also, the view isn't less secure than model/controller - it's still php parsed only by the server ;)

Comment: The function for the AppModel works perfectly! I have now implemented isAuthorized, but there's one thing I do not understand. Why do I find the recipe to edit in the isAuthorized function? And can I stop it from redirecting and instead show a message or something? Do I just put a redirect in the isAuthorized function?

Comment: @Kvothe It looks better now, even though your explanation doesn't match the code, and if I'd wanted to be picky, then I'd say it's better to use strict comparison `===`, also you could use `Model::field()` instead. The `isOwnedBy()` method still seems wonky, as its name kinda suggests that the passed value is being compared to the current data in the model instance. Regarding the security problem that I've mentioned, I was referring to hiding the links, just hiding them doesn't provide any security whatsoever, as it doesn't stop people from manually invoking the URLs.